# Files in AWS Fargate

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

Is it possible to actualy write/edit/delete files in Fargate ?

Since it's serverless and it doesn't really have a filesystem, 
I couldn't get a clear answer about this.

For example, one of our clients needs to write some temporary cache files on the local container.
Is this possible ?

I don't want to setup a whole Data Container Volume just for this..

Thanks !

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Fargate runs containers. It is Containers as a Service (CaaS). Your container (Docker) can be anything, Linux, Windows etc. You DO have a filesystem in Fargate, it is OS filesystem whatever you setup in your container. Your application is deployed on this file system and the OS user running your application has whatever permissions to the local filesystem that you give it in the container.

The file system is ephemeral meaning when your Fargate task stops and is destroyed, your local storage will be destroyed with it.  It is also limited to a small amount of storage, maybe 10GB.

In Fargate you actually cannot mount a volume, like an EBS volume. If you need to do this you have to use EC2 launch type task in ECS instead of Fargate launch type ECS tasks if you want to use containers, or use a raw EC2 instance.  This does not prevent you from read/write/delete access to the local file system inside your container.

So you can write local temp files just fine. If you need to persist the data after the life of the Fargate task or very large amounts of data, you need to write to some other storage like S3 or RDS.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/fargate-task-storage.html

Edit: Mounting EFS volumes in ECS and Fargate is now [generally available](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2020/04/amazon-ecs-aws-fargate-support-amazon-efs-filesystems-generally-available/).

Comment: @Mark B it was intentional when I said you can mount EBS volumes in ECS service, just not using Fargate tasks. It is correct you can mount EBS volumes in EC2, but I am assuming the author of the questions wants to continue to use containers using the ECS service and not spin up there own raw EC2 instances. You can mount EBS from ECS when the task/launch type is ECS. I changed it back and added some clarification. Thank you for the other edits. Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/amazon-ecs-and-docker-volume-drivers-amazon-ebs/

Comment: There are 2 task launch types for ECS: EC2 or Fargate as documented and illustrated here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/launch_types.html. You would need to use the EC2 launch type in ECS, which launches your ECS containers onto an EC2 host machine, in order to mount volumes. It doesn't make sense to call something an "ECS task launch type of ECS". Note how even in the reference you linked, they use the following: `"launchType": "EC2"`

Comment: Okay I see your point and you are correct my terminology was off. Thank you again. I gave my answer an additional revision, feel free to clean it up further if you think it is needed.