# Scapy in container on AWS ECS does not download or create files

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, docker, scrapy, containers

I have Scrapy running in a Docker container, deployed on AWS ECS.

If I run build and run the Docker container locally, it correctly downloads images into the folder specified in the image store variable:

```
'IMAGES_STORE':../project/scraper_files/spiders/whats_new_from_date_" + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
```

However, when I run the same container on AWS ECS, the images do not seem to appear anywhere in the container's file system. I am basing that on this code:

```
walks = os.walk(os.getcwd())
ll = list(os.walk(os.getcwd()))
for source, dirs, files in ll:
    print(files)
```

When I run the container locally, my JPEG files are listed. When I run the container on ECS, only the original files that were mounted when the container was built are listed.

Is the use of a relative file path in IMAGES_STORE a mistake? Is the use of the OS module misled within a container? Are the images in fact downloading but to somewhere else? I need to find out if/where the image files are downloading to when I run the script in ECS.

Another area I thought might be the culprit is my Bash script, which is the Dockerfile Entrypoint:

```
scrapy crawl imagesearch-spider
python to_s3.py
```

Because container storage is ephemeral, could it be that the images are downloading correctly via Scrapy, but getting removed before the Python script runs?

I am new to this so any help in finding the images/getting them to download would be appreciated. For reference, I then upload all the image files to S3 (this part of the process works fine in ECS just so long the image files can be located).

Answer (score 0):

if you used ECS default settings, I think it defaults to use FARGATE. And in FARGATE you can't access the filesystem.

Container storage is ephemeral but doesn't vanish while it's running.

My opinion is that you best bet is to directly use `boto3` to upload the files to S3, no need to use Bash.

Comment: Hi there, I have had no problem using Boto3 in my to_s3.py script to upload files from the file system, so you must be able to access it in Fargate. I am using Fargate because it's good for my use case. The only issue is finding the new image files, it can access existing ones. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58167377/files-in-aws-fargate

Answer (score 0):

The solution to this was to check the current working directory in the container, which was

```
/usr/local/bin
```

Updating the image store file path to match this solved the problem:

```
'IMAGES_STORE': '/usr/local/bin/whats_new_from_date_' + datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y%m%d%H%M')
```